# JavaScript code to add buttons to page

Tags: javascript

I have this very simple code:

```
<body onload="OnLoad()">
    <script>
        function OnLoad() {

        for (i = 0 i < 3; ++i)
        {
                var name = 'Test' + i;
                var menuBtn = document.createElement('input');
                menuBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                menuBtn.setAttribute('value', name);
                menuBtn.setAttribute('name', name);
                menuBtn.setAttribute('id', name);
                document.body.appendChild(menuBtn);
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

You can see it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUAag/) If I remove the for loop it works fine. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Always check your error console, kids.

Comment: I must say I don't understand this downvoting..is there anything fundamentally wrong with question? is it off topic? does it show lack of effort from my front? It may be simple oversight,but doesn't deserve downvotes IMHO.

Comment: You're right, I suppose. I think you just got downvotes because it's such a simple mistake, and nothing can really be learned from it. People should always be checking their error consoles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one SemiColon is missing in your for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
```

It should solve the problem

Comment: it happens... don't feel so !

Comment: @Asha Because you don't use the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 2):

Your error lies here `(i = 0 i < 3; ++i)`

Instead use this

```
(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a semicolon in your for loop after the `i = 0`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
```